# Not able to feed the combined SMOTE & RandomUnderSampler pipeline into the main pipeline

Tags: scikit-learn, gridsearchcv, imbalanced-data, imblearn, smote

I am currently working with an Imbalanced datatset, and inorder to handle Imbalance, I plan on combining SMOTE and ADASYN with RandomUnderSampler, and also indivitual undersampling, oversampling, SMOTE & ADASYN (A total of 6 sampling ways, which I will pass as a paramenter in GridSearchCV). I created two pipelines for this.

```
Smote_Under_pipeline = imb_Pipeline([
     ('smote', SMOTE(random_state=rnd_state, n_jobs=-1)),
     ('under', RandomUnderSampler(random_state=rnd_state)),
])

Adasyn_Under_pipeline = imb_Pipeline([
     ('adasyn', ADASYN(random_state=rnd_state, n_jobs=-1)),
     ('under', RandomUnderSampler(random_state=rnd_state)), 
])
```

My plan is to feed this two pipleines into the main pipeline, which is like this:

```
Main_Pipeline = imb_Pipeline([
     ('feature_handler', FeatureTransformer(list(pearson_feature_vector.index))),
     ('imb', Smote_Under_pipeline),
     ('scaler', StandardScaler()),
     ('pca', PCA(n_components=0.99)),
     ('model', LogisticRegression(max_iter=1750)),
])
```

The *FeatureTransformer()* is a feature selector class:

```
class FeatureTransformer(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):

    def __init__(self, feature_vector=None):
        self.feature_vector = feature_vector
    
    def fit(self, X, y):
        return self

    def transform(self, X):
        return X[self.feature_vector]
```

When I call *Smote_Under_pipeline.fit()* or *Adasyn_Under_pipeline.fit()*, It works (sample code below):

```
dumm_x, dumm_y = Smote_Under_pipeline.fit_resample(X_train, y_train)
```

But when I try to initialize *Main_Pipeline* at that time interpreter throws an error:

```
TypeError: All intermediate steps of the chain should be estimators that implement fit and transform or fit_resample. 'Pipeline(steps=[('smote', SMOTE(n_jobs=-1, random_state=42)),
            ('under', RandomUnderSampler(random_state=42))])' implements both)
```

I am using pipelines provided by *Imbalance-learn*.

I am not able to understand the error. While using scikit-learn pipelines all the intermediate estimators have their own *fit()* & *fit_transform()* methods, The imblearn pipelines give an additionally functionality of handling *fit_resample()* method, which is being exposed by both: *Smote_Under_pipeline* & *Adasyn_Under_pipeline*. So, it can be called in the *Main_Pipeline*, then why is the error being thrown? Both the sampling pipelines are exposing *fit()* method as well along with *fit_resample()*, is this the cause?

Comment: The error message suggests that the problem is that the `Smote_Under_pipeline` has both `transform` and `fit_resample`.  Perhaps the `imblearn` pipelines have to decide whether to resample or transform, and in this case it's ambiguous which to use?  Maybe the best thing to do is just unpack the `Smote_Under_pipeline`, putting smote and undersampling into the larger pipeline directly?

Comment: @Ben Reiniger, But, since `RandomUnderSampler` doesn't have a `transform` method, `Smote_Under_pipeline` also does not have `transform` method. Only `fit` and `fit_resample` methods are present. And, the error states either `fit and transform` or `fit_resample` should be present. Since, `transform` is not present, first condition is not met, and because `fit_resample` is present, the second condition is met, then shouldn't it execute using only `fit_resample`?

Comment: @BenReiniger Also, About putting smote and undersampling in larger pipeline, are you implying I should put them into `Main_Pipeline`? If it is, then since I mentioned I want to implement 6 ways of imbalance handling for cmparing all, so, I cannot put smote and undersampling in `Main_Pipeline`. If this is not what you are implying, I was not able to understand what you are saying. Would be glad if you can elaborate. Thank you.

Comment: Ben Reiniger is completely right. There is an ambiguity because the imbalanced-learn pipeline defines both `fit`/`transform` and `fit_resample`. The solution is to make a flat pipeline having the over-sampling followed by the under-sampling.

```
Main_Pipeline = imb_Pipeline([
     ('feature_handler', FeatureTransformer(list(pearson_feature_vector.index))),
     ('smote', SMOTE()),
     ('random_under_sampler', RandomUnderSampler()),
     ('scaler', StandardScaler()),
     ('pca', PCA(n_components=0.99)),
     ('model', LogisticRegression(max_iter=1750)),
])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To emphasize @glemaitre's comment, it's the *pipeline* (the inner one) that has both transform and resampling that's causing the problem.

So flattening the pipeline (including the resamplers directly in the main pipeline) seems to be the solution.  You may be able to test the different resampling strategies as hyperparameters still, by turning off individual steps:

```py
Main_Pipeline = imb_Pipeline([
     ('feature_handler', FeatureTransformer(list(pearson_feature_vector.index))),
     ('oversamp', None),
     ('undersamp', None),
     ('scaler', StandardScaler()),
     ('pca', PCA(n_components=0.99)),
     ('model', LogisticRegression(max_iter=1750)),
])

param_space = {
    'oversamp': [None, SMOTE(...), ADASYN(...), RandomOverSampler(...)],
    'undersamp': [None, RandomUnderSampler(...)],
    ...,
}
```

That will give 8 combinations, including the None-None and over-undersample in addition to those you wanted.  But that seems OK to me: it'll be nice to have the comparison to the no-resampling pipeline, and over-undersampling is similar to the synth-undersampling combinations.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this approach!!

Comment: I'm not too familiar with `imblearn`, but one concern is "how balanced" these will make things. If `oversamp` balances the classes, then `RandomUnderSampler` probably won't get to do anything, but if `oversamp` just partially balances, then when paired with `undersamp=None` the final classes won't be balanced.

Comment: You are correct, but since we don't know whether the data generated/removed from sampling is useful or noise, sometimes a tiny bit of extra oversampling/undersampling above the required can cause the model to overfit/underfit. It can be that a perfectly balanced dataset has more noise than one with slight imbalance. So, I think a little imbalance is alright.